# AngularJs post form data to server by $q and respones delayed,$location doen't work

Tags: angularjs

I want to create login form,then submit it to server-side and redirect if response success.because of delayed,$location doen't work.

When subimt it again(submit current form twice),it redirect.so what's the problem?

And when i try to use if else instead of dojo.ajax to check user account, redirect works. so i think the key reason is delayed.

And i try to use resolve to handle post,but i found that it's hard to get form data by $scope,actually $scope doen't work yet.could you have any solutions for this case?

controller.js

```
    $scope.loginForm = function(){
        var loginInfo = {
                "userName":$scope.formData.userName,
                "passWord":$scope.formData.passWord
        };
        //$scope.msgText='asfdasfd';
        loginService.getLoginData(loginInfo,loginSuccess);
     };

     var loginSuccess = function(data){
        console.log('loginSuccess works//'+data);
        if(data){
            $location.path('/admin');
            console.log($location.path());
        }else{
            $scope.msgText='error';
        }
    }
}]);
```

Service.js

```
var serviceFn = {
        'getLoginData':getLoginData
};

return serviceFn;

function getLoginData(loginInfo,success){
    var data= true;
    var d = $q.defer();
    //return success(data);
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url:"/xxx?sign_in_mail="+loginInfo.userName+"&sign_in_pwd="+loginInfo.passWord,
        handleAs: "json"
     }).then(function(res){             
        d.resolve(res.items);
        if(res.items == "Success"){
            console.log(res.items+"////from service");
            data = true;

        }else{
            data = false
            console.log(res.items);
        }
    }).then(function(){
        return success(data)
    });
}
```

}]);

Comment: Why do you use dojo to send http requests? Angular has a $http service to do that. Have you tried wrapping your dojo callback into a function passed to scope.$apply()? You're doing things behind the back of angular by using dojo.

Comment: BTW, never, ever put password in the URL. If you are sending a post, put it into the "data". URL could appear in logs, very not secure.

Comment: yep,it's best way to use $http service to handle post.but for my app,json is't  strictly({name:"xxx"}),so some problem appeared when i used $http. and i glad to know if have solution for this.

Comment: are you using ui-router or ngRoute? if ui-router, that most likely won't work.

Comment: use ui-router.state('login_index', {
            url: '/',
            views:{
                '' :{templateUrl:'tpls/login_index.html'},
                'img@login_index' :{
                    templateUrl:'tpls/login-image.html'
                },
                'content@login_index':{
                 templateUrl:'tpls/login-form.html',
                 controller:'loginCtrl'
                 }
            }
        }).

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to use out-of-angular service, use the $scope.$digest() command, so angularjs would know when to check the variables for change and so, update the UI.

```
var loginSuccess = function(data){
    console.log('loginSuccess works//'+data);
    if(data){
        $location.path('/admin');
        console.log($location.path());
    }else{
        $scope.msgText='error';
    }
    $scope.$digest(); // "Hey, AngularJS, check the variables, you know..."
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. could you provide more detail for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
     var loginSuccess = function(data){
        console.log('loginSuccess works//'+data);
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            if(data){
                $location.path('/admin');
                console.log($location.path());
                $scope.status = true;
            }else{
                $scope.msgText='error';
            }
        });
    };
```

Thanks all of you, solution as above.